# Problems using GameplayKit's pathfinding wander behaviour

Tags: swift, path-finding

I have a couple of entities moving around the scene and they automatically avoid the physic body obstacles using the built in behaviour, although when it comes to the walls that I have surrounded the scene with, they get stuck in the corners.

Obstacles and walls are one and the same as defined in Scene Editor.

My question is how can I resolve this issue?

a)  is their a way to define the size of the SKGraph, e.g. like defining the size of the physics game world?  So GameplayKit's pathfinding constrains the graph model to the game world size.

b) should I use Rules as well as wander behaviour to avoid or turn away from walls?

My question is a bit vague, but I am asking for opinions as well solutions if you should have any!

Cheers

Comment: you need to elaborate more

Comment: So I have been investigating SKGraphs.  I have been trying to implement SKMeshGraph, <br/> let graph = GKMeshGraph(bufferRadius: GameplayConfiguration.TaskBot.pathfindingGraphBufferRadius, minCoordinate: float2(0.0,0.0), maxCoordinate: float2(1400.0,1000.0) ) <br/> My scene size is 1400, 1000, anchor: 0.5,0.5 <br/>